# Django object isn't saving username with get_or_create()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to save my TagStatus object. Right now it's saving, however its not saving the username, nor is it saving the tag foreign key.

Whats its saving right now is this:

```
user : __________ (empty) 
status : Status 2 
tag : _________ (empty)
```

**What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the username or tag saving?** Thank you for your help in advance.

**the model:**

```
class TagStatus(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tag_statuses)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**my view:**

```
@login_required
def tags(request):
    all_tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = base_context(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'status_check' in request.POST:
            status = int(request.POST['select'])
            tag = request.POST['tag']
            user = request.user
            try:
                tag_status = TagStatus.objects.get_or_create(status=status, tag__slug=tag, user__username=user.username)
            except TagStatus.DoesNotExist:
                tag_status = None
            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Successfully changed status"})
        else:
            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Error"})
            return HttpResponse (response, mimetype='application/json')
    status_form = TagStatusForm()
    context['all_tags'] = all_tags
    return render_to_response('tags/tags.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
<form class="nice" id="status-form" method="POST" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" name="status_check" />
     <input type='hidden' name="tag" value="{{ tag.slug }}" />
     <select name="select" id="positionSelect" class="input-text category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option name="all" value="0">Your Status</option>
          <option name="investing" value="1">Status 1</option>
          <option name="selling" value="2">Status 2</option>
          <option name="interested" value="3">Status 3</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you use `get_or_create` in adding new tag. You have to use `get_or_create`, if you are both doing querying or saving. What I saw in your view is your just adding it, no querying. So why you make it difficult if you can just put it,

```
new_tag = Tag.object.create(slug=tag)
TagStatus.objects.create(status=status, tag=new_tag, user=user)
```

That will solve your problem.

```
@login_required
def tags(request):
    all_tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = base_context(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'status_check' in request.POST:
            status = int(request.POST['select'])
            tag = request.POST['tag']
            user = request.user

            new_tag = Tag.object.create(slug=tag)
            TagStatus.objects.create(status=status, tag=new_tag, user=user)

            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Successfully changed status"})
        else:
            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Error"})
            return HttpResponse (response, mimetype='application/json')
    status_form = TagStatusForm()
    context['all_tags'] = all_tags
    return render_to_response('tags/tags.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: `TagStatus.objects.create(status=status, tag=new_tag, user=user)` did the trick + `new_tag = Tag.objects.get(id=tag)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this:
Change:

```
tag_status = TagStatus.objects.get_or_create(status=status, tag__slug=tag, user__username=user.username)
```

to:

```
tag_status, _ = TagStatus.objects.get_or_create(status=status, tag=tag, user=user, defaults={'user': user, 'tag': tag})
tag_status.save()
```

Also, `tag` should be of `Tag` instance, you can do:

```
tag, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(slug=request.POST['tag'])
```

If slug is a slug_field, you can do `slugify(request.POST['tag'])` 
the `get_or_create` returns 2 parameters - one is the object, the other is the `created = True/False` to depict if a new object was created

Also, `TagStatus.DoesNotExist` will never occur since you are using `get_or_create`

Comment: this actually returns a `Value Error: Cannot assign "u'internet'": "TagStatus.tag" must be a "Tag" instance.` I'm assuming it has something to do with`tag__slug`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem you should be passing a tag object here not a string otherwise this solution  should work. You should save the tag object somewhere . tag.slug=request.POST['tag'] ; tag.save() and then TagStatus.objects.get_or_create(status=status, tag=tag,user=user, defaults={'user': user, 'tag': tag})

Comment: @dusual, believe it or not that seemed to solve the username issue. But it didn't save the Tag. :\

Comment: one more edit: tag__slug should be just tag. That should work now. We are very close to the solution.

Comment: @dusual i cannot comment on your answer, but i dont think `tag.slug; tag.save()` will work, because you are not creating an object. `Tag.objects.create(slug=request.POST[''tag])` should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong with your code, but this is not what you should be doing. Django forms handle all of this stuff for you automatically--the creation of the form, the conversion from post data to python data, and saving the model. They also do lots of validation that is really really helpful that you would never figure out how to do yourself.

Please see the Django form documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already played with django forms, ModelForms. And neither suited the task due to the form needing hidden inputs holding the value of the foreignkey `Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from @user2246087 answer just add the following:

```
tag.slug = request.POST['tag']
tag.save()
```

and then

```
tag_status, created = TagStatus.objects.get_or_create(status=status, tag=tag, user=user, defaults={'user': user, 'tag': tag})
```

You do not need to add the TagStatus.save()